# Outputting a null var in a if statement?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am returned either a 1 or null from a method in a third party package. I need to check this in a vue template statement like so:

```
v-if="{{ $myVar }} || {{ $thirdPartVar }}"
```

Either var needs to be true.

The issue is when the $thirdPartyVar is null, the statement errors as there is nothing after the ||.

How can I output a null var to be true or false in this situation?

The error is: `- invalid expression: Unexpected token }`

Comment: _Statement errors_ Can you show us the error message please, so we dont have to guess.

Comment: try `json_encode($thirdPartVar)`

Answer (score -1):

You should remove the extra brackets because it's not a valid vue template syntax

```
v-if="$myVar || $thirdPartVar"
```

Comment: But {{}} are outputting blade vars